# Why isn't !locks working for me?

Tags: debugging, windbg, locks

I'm using windbg (the latest available from the MSDN download page).

I'm trying to debug a deadlock in my app, and !locks would be very useful.  However, it's not working:

```
0:023> !locks NTSDEXTS: Unable to resolve ntdll!RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG type
NTSDEXTS: Please check your symbols
```

I don't know why it's upset.  I've got symbols properly loaded:

```
0:023> .sympath
Symbol search path is: srv*
Expanded Symbol search path is: cache*c:\debuggers\sym;SRV*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

And NTSD agrees:

```
0:023> lmv m ntdll
start    end        module name
777b0000 77930000   ntdll      (pdb symbols)          c:\debuggers\sym\wntdll.pdb\E9D10FA3EB884A23A5854E04FB7E2F0C2\wntdll.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
    Image path: ntdll.dll
    Image name: ntdll.dll
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:11:23 2009 (4A5BDB3B)
    CheckSum:         00148A78
    ImageSize:        00180000
    File version:     6.1.7600.16385
    Product version:  6.1.7600.16385
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
    InternalName:     ntdll.dll
    OriginalFilename: ntdll.dll
    ProductVersion:   6.1.7600.16385
    FileVersion:      6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)
    FileDescription:  NT Layer DLL
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

And the stack looks good:

```
0:036> k
ChildEBP RetAddr  
1506fdd8 7784f546 ntdll!DbgBreakPoint
1506fe08 75bf3677 ntdll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin+0x3c
1506fe14 777e9d72 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
1506fe54 777e9d45 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
1506fe6c 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Useful link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150405042817/http://www.voyce.com/index.php/2009/06/03/windbg-locks-command-broken/).

The correct version that fixes this is 6.12.2.633.  It's part of [WDK 7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=36a2630f-5d56-43b5-b996-7633f2ec14ff) in the "debuggers" folder in the root of the DVD (.iso).

Alternatively, grab the [WDK 7.1 web installer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=6b6c21d2-2006-4afa-9702-529fa782d63b) and install "just" Debugging Tools for Windows (though that seems to involve a hundred odd megabytes of extraneous material that does not correspond with any of the checkboxes in the installer).

---

dlanod comments:

> I also found [msdn-archives](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/debugtoolswindows/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx)
>   which lets you download standalone versions of the new release.

And this link does in fact work. (Much better than the WDK installer)

Comment: I also found http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/debugtoolswindows/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4912 which lets you download standalone versions of the new release.

Comment: "The Archive Gallery has been retired."

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736250/getting-windbg-without-the-whole-wdk