# IE 6.0 crashing when printing from my web application

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging, crash

When clicking on print button the second time from my app, IE 6.0 is crashing. 
Steps to reproduce: 
1) Click on print Button and cancel the print dialog. 
2) Click on print again. IE 6.0 crashes.

It works fine in IE 7 & 8.

Below is the stack trace i got from WinDbg.

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.11.0001.404 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

*** wait with pending attach
Symbol search path is: srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00400000 00419000   C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
ModLoad: 7c900000 7c9b2000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 5ad10000 5ad59000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\verifier.dll
ModLoad: 7c800000 7c8f6000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
ModLoad: 77c10000 77c68000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 7e410000 7e4a1000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
ModLoad: 77f10000 77f59000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
ModLoad: 77f60000 77fd6000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
ModLoad: 77dd0000 77e6b000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 77e70000 77f02000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
ModLoad: 77fe0000 77ff1000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
ModLoad: 7e290000 7e403000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHDOCVW.dll
ModLoad: 77a80000 77b15000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\CRYPT32.dll
ModLoad: 77b20000 77b32000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSASN1.dll
ModLoad: 754d0000 75550000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\CRYPTUI.dll
ModLoad: 5b860000 5b8b5000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\NETAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 77120000 771ab000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
ModLoad: 774e0000 7761d000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
ModLoad: 77c00000 77c08000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\VERSION.dll
ModLoad: 771b0000 7725a000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WININET.dll
ModLoad: 76c30000 76c5e000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINTRUST.dll
ModLoad: 76c90000 76cb8000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMAGEHLP.dll
ModLoad: 76f60000 76f8c000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WLDAP32.dll
ModLoad: 773d0000 774d3000   C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.5512_x-ww_35d4ce83\comctl32.dll
ModLoad: 7c9c0000 7d1d7000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
ModLoad: 5d090000 5d12a000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\comctl32.dll
ModLoad: 5ad70000 5ada8000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
ModLoad: 75f80000 7607d000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\BROWSEUI.dll
ModLoad: 71600000 71612000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\browselc.dll
ModLoad: 77b40000 77b62000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\appHelp.dll
ModLoad: 76fd0000 7704f000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\CLBCATQ.DLL
ModLoad: 77050000 77115000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMRes.dll
ModLoad: 77a20000 77a74000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\cscui.dll
ModLoad: 76600000 7661d000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\CSCDLL.dll
ModLoad: 77920000 77a13000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
ModLoad: 10000000 10098000   C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar\IEDevToolbar.dll
ModLoad: 7e1e0000 7e282000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\urlmon.dll
ModLoad: 71ab0000 71ac7000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
ModLoad: 71aa0000 71aa8000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
ModLoad: 76380000 76385000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSIMG32.dll
ModLoad: 75cf0000 75d81000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\mlang.dll
ModLoad: 75c50000 75ccd000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\jscript.dll
ModLoad: 02fc0000 03285000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\xpsp2res.dll
ModLoad: 7d1e0000 7d49c000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\msi.dll
ModLoad: 034a0000 034cb000   C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar\SelectorObjectAPI.dll
ModLoad: 7dc30000 7df23000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\mshtml.dll
ModLoad: 746c0000 746e7000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\msls31.dll
ModLoad: 76bf0000 76bfb000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
ModLoad: 71800000 71888000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\shdoclc.dll
ModLoad: 7e720000 7e7d0000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\SXS.DLL
ModLoad: 746f0000 7471a000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\msimtf.dll
ModLoad: 74720000 7476c000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll
ModLoad: 76390000 763ad000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
ModLoad: 76b40000 76b6d000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
ModLoad: 71ad0000 71ad9000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\wsock32.dll
ModLoad: 71a50000 71a8f000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
ModLoad: 662b0000 66308000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\hnetcfg.dll
ModLoad: 71a90000 71a98000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\wshtcpip.dll
ModLoad: 76ee0000 76f1c000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\RASAPI32.DLL
ModLoad: 76e90000 76ea2000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasman.dll
ModLoad: 76eb0000 76edf000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\TAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 76e80000 76e8e000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\rtutils.dll
ModLoad: 722b0000 722b5000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\sensapi.dll
ModLoad: 769c0000 76a74000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\USERENV.dll
ModLoad: 76fc0000 76fc6000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasadhlp.dll
ModLoad: 65af0000 65af7000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\jsproxy.dll
ModLoad: 76f20000 76f47000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\DNSAPI.dll
ModLoad: 76fb0000 76fb8000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
ModLoad: 76200000 76271000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\mshtmled.dll
ModLoad: 73300000 7336a000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\vbscript.dll
ModLoad: 79000000 7904a000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\mscoree.dll
ModLoad: 603b0000 60416000   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
ModLoad: 63f00000 63f0c000   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorie.dll
ModLoad: 78130000 781cb000   C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.42_x-ww_0de06acd\MSVCR80.dll
ModLoad: 63f50000 63f68000   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorld.dll
ModLoad: 64020000 64033000   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorsec.dll
ModLoad: 79e70000 7a3d1000   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
ModLoad: 68000000 68036000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
ModLoad: 75e60000 75e73000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\cryptnet.dll
ModLoad: 4d4f0000 4d549000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINHTTP.dll
ModLoad: 790c0000 794de000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
ModLoad: 79060000 790b3000   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorjit.dll
ModLoad: 60650000 6065c000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\IEHost\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\IEHost.dll
ModLoad: 60680000 60688000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\IIEHost\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\IIEHost.dll
ModLoad: 7a440000 7a724000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll
ModLoad: 09b40000 09b4e000   C:\Documents and Settings\XPMUser\Local Settings\Application Data\assembly\dl3\E3M2391O.8H6\BV1W0628.PXV\a3363ef0\00f2c4a7_4048cb01\TimeoutPopup.DLL
ModLoad: 7afd0000 7b4e6000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll
ModLoad: 7ade0000 7ae8e000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll
ModLoad: 60000000 60008000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll
ModLoad: 4ec50000 4edf6000   C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.GdiPlus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.0.2600.5581_x-ww_dfbc4fc4\gdiplus.dll
ModLoad: 0a890000 0a8a4000   C:\Documents and Settings\XPMUser\Local Settings\Application Data\assembly\dl3\E3M2391O.8H6\BV1W0628.PXV\9215ad46\809684af_4048cb01\Skeleton.DLL
ModLoad: 0a9b0000 0a9ba000   C:\Documents and Settings\XPMUser\Local Settings\Application Data\assembly\dl3\E3M2391O.8H6\BV1W0628.PXV\2e5b7e27\800ff1ab_4048cb01\Core.DLL
ModLoad: 0a9c0000 0a9d0000   C:\Documents and Settings\XPMUser\Local Settings\Application Data\assembly\dl3\E3M2391O.8H6\BV1W0628.PXV\dd69ee7a\80c3b5b0_4048cb01\Framework.DLL
ModLoad: 69be0000 69dd4000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll
ModLoad: 0ac20000 0ac48000   C:\Documents and Settings\XPMUser\Local Settings\Application Data\assembly\dl3\E3M2391O.8H6\BV1W0628.PXV\66f5f966\002d1db0_4048cb01\Foundation.DLL
ModLoad: 0aee0000 0b4c3000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash\Flash10i.ocx
ModLoad: 73f10000 73f6c000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\DSOUND.dll
ModLoad: 763b0000 763f9000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMDLG32.dll
ModLoad: 73b30000 73b45000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\mscms.dll
ModLoad: 73000000 73026000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
ModLoad: 767f0000 76817000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\schannel.dll
ModLoad: 6d430000 6d43a000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\ddrawex.dll
ModLoad: 73760000 737ab000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\DDRAW.dll
ModLoad: 73bc0000 73bc6000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\DCIMAN32.dll
ModLoad: 0fc80000 0fcc4000   C:\Documents and Settings\XPMUser\Local Settings\Application Data\assembly\dl3\E3M2391O.8H6\BV1W0628.PXV\0ced6b70\809684af_4048cb01\PCE.DLL
ModLoad: 74980000 74a94000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\msxml3.dll
ModLoad: 6bdd0000 6be06000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\dxtrans.dll
ModLoad: 76b20000 76b31000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\ATL.DLL
ModLoad: 6be10000 6be6a000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\dxtmsft.dll
ModLoad: 64e70000 65137000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
ModLoad: 66880000 6688c000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\ImgUtil.dll
ModLoad: 5e310000 5e31c000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\pngfilt.dll
ModLoad: 71d40000 71d5b000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\actxprxy.dll
ModLoad: 5ff50000 5ff61000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\msratelc.dll
ModLoad: 6cc60000 6cc68000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\dispex.dll
ModLoad: 74b80000 74c0c000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\printui.dll
ModLoad: 77cc0000 77cf2000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\ACTIVEDS.dll
ModLoad: 76e10000 76e35000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\adsldpc.dll
ModLoad: 74ae0000 74ae7000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
ModLoad: 71b20000 71b32000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\MPR.dll
(a48.abc): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=7ffdf000 ebx=00000001 ecx=00000002 edx=00000003 esi=00000004 edi=00000005
eip=7c90120e esp=03edffcc ebp=03edfff4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=0038  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
7c90120e cc              int     3
Missing image name, possible paged-out or corrupt data.
Missing image name, possible paged-out or corrupt data.
Missing image name, possible paged-out or corrupt data.


k
ChildEBP RetAddr  
0584ffc8 7c951e40 ntdll!DbgBreakPoint
0584fff4 00000000 ntdll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin+0x2d
```

I am a newbie at using WinDbg, can someone help me with this

Comment: So, this break is the normal "I just attached and now I might want to enter some commands" breakpoint.  That's why the stack isn't very useful.  You want to enter the `g` command (Go), which will start IE running, then do whatever you do to get IE to crash.  The debugger will break again, and you can then type `kP` to get a nice stack where the actual issue occurs.  Also, type `!symfix` and `.reload` before you dump the stack to make sure you have symbols setup.

Comment: Also, you're using a shitty version (6.11) of the debugger.  You can download 6.12 as part of the WDK. See http://www.voyce.com/index.php/2009/06/03/windbg-locks-command-broken/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876506/why-isnt-locks-working-for-me

Answer (score 3):

You need to file an issue with Microsoft.

You could try to disable all browser plugins and toolbars as well.  I wouldn't troubleshoot it much further than that though.  IMO if IE needs a patch to get this fixed, you might as well just install IE8.

Comment: The browser does not have any plug-ins and tool bars installed. Installing IE 8 is not an option right not because people who access our app use IE 6.0

Comment: Then all you can do is file an issue with Microsoft and press the issue with your users as much as possible to upgrade to IE 8.  You will find very, very little *community* support for any technical aspect of IE6 beyond the very basics of getting elements to style acceptably and getting JavaScript functions to just work.   I'm willing to bet that MS will also tell you to tell your users to upgrade as well, even though they are technically beholden to help you out if you have a support agreement with them.