# IE 6 is crashing when printing from my web application

Tags: internet-explorer, crash-dumps, printing-web-page

When clicking on print button the second time from my app, IE 6.0 is crashing.

Steps to reproduce: 1) Click on print Button and cancel the print dialog. 2) Click on print again. IE 6.0 crashes.

It works fine in IE 7 & 8.

Below is the stack trace i got from WinDbg.

```
0:000> g
(730.9e0): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
eax=00000058 ebx=00000000 ecx=0160de40 edx=00000016 esi=0103f154 edi=00000000
eip=013556cd esp=001360a8 ebp=001360c0 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00250246
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Program Files\Google\Google Toolbar\Component\GoogleToolbarDynamic_32_78F32466E61F1EEC.dll - 
GoogleToolbarDynamic_32_78F32466E61F1EEC!DllCanUnloadNow+0x37501:
013556cd 3b30            cmp     esi,dword ptr [eax]  ds:0023:00000058=????????


0:000> kp
ChildEBP RetAddr  
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
001360c0 01355830 GoogleToolbarDynamic_32_78F32466E61F1EEC!DllCanUnloadNow+0x37501
001360d4 01355851 GoogleToolbarDynamic_32_78F32466E61F1EEC!DllCanUnloadNow+0x37664
00136130 013dc77e GoogleToolbarDynamic_32_78F32466E61F1EEC!DllCanUnloadNow+0x37685
001361c0 01386059 GoogleToolbarDynamic_32_78F32466E61F1EEC!DllCanUnloadNow+0xbe5b2
001361e8 0137d30a GoogleToolbarDynamic_32_78F32466E61F1EEC!DllCanUnloadNow+0x67e8d
00136228 0137d374 GoogleToolbarDynamic_32_78F32466E61F1EEC!DllCanUnloadNow+0x5f13e
00136250 7c923ada GoogleToolbarDynamic_32_78F32466E61F1EEC!DllCanUnloadNow+0x5f1a8
001362d4 7c81caae ntdll!LdrShutdownProcess+0x14f
001363c8 7c81cb26 kernel32!_ExitProcess+0x42
001363dc 79fdc424 kernel32!ExitProcess+0x14
00136604 7a096786 mscorwks!SafeExitProcess+0x157
00136610 7a0979b9 mscorwks!EEPolicy::HandleFatalError+0x55
00136634 79f8e993 mscorwks!CLRVectoredExceptionHandlerPhase3+0xbc
00136668 79f8e835 mscorwks!CLRVectoredExceptionHandlerPhase2+0x20
0013669c 79ef4558 mscorwks!CLRVectoredExceptionHandler+0x10a
001366c8 79ef4755 mscorwks!CPFH_RealFirstPassHandler+0x607
001366ec 7c9032a8 mscorwks!COMPlusFrameHandler+0x15a
00136710 7c90327a ntdll!ExecuteHandler2+0x26
001367c0 7c90e48a ntdll!ExecuteHandler+0x24
001367c0 79fc0a7d ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0xe
00136ad4 79fc0ab0 mscorwks!WKS::gc_heap::sweep_large_objects+0x114
00136af8 79f7640f mscorwks!WKS::gc_heap::mark_phase+0x1eb
00136b1c 79f76995 mscorwks!WKS::gc_heap::gc1+0x62
00136b30 79f766aa mscorwks!WKS::gc_heap::garbage_collect+0x253
00136b5c 79f78576 mscorwks!WKS::GCHeap::GarbageCollectGeneration+0x1a9
00136be8 79f75e1e mscorwks!WKS::gc_heap::try_allocate_more_space+0x15b
00136bfc 79f75eb9 mscorwks!WKS::gc_heap::allocate_more_space+0x11
00136c1c 79e732c1 mscorwks!WKS::GCHeap::Alloc+0x3b
00136c38 79e7d904 mscorwks!Alloc+0x60
00136c74 79e990c6 mscorwks!SlowAllocateString+0x29
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\mscorlib\7bffd7ff2009f421fe5d229927588496\mscorlib.ni.dll
00136d18 792e18ce mscorwks!FramedAllocateString+0xa1
00136d38 792e1a26 mscorlib_ni+0x2218ce
00136d50 792e1992 mscorlib_ni+0x221a26
00136d70 7974c62f mscorlib_ni+0x221992
00136d80 7974c73b mscorlib_ni+0x68c62f
00136da4 7974ba37 mscorlib_ni+0x68c73b
00136dc0 7974bf34 mscorlib_ni+0x68ba37
00136e24 7978c030 mscorlib_ni+0x68bf34
00136e58 7978bf91 mscorlib_ni+0x6cc030
00136e80 7978b972 mscorlib_ni+0x6cbf91
00136ed0 797d8ac6 mscorlib_ni+0x6cb972
00136ef8 797d8973 mscorlib_ni+0x718ac6
00136f1c 797d87ef mscorlib_ni+0x718973
00136f2c 797d7a9d mscorlib_ni+0x7187ef
00136f40 7978c168 mscorlib_ni+0x717a9d
00136f58 7978c08f mscorlib_ni+0x6cc168
00136f70 79e71b4c mscorlib_ni+0x6cc08f
00136f80 79e821f9 mscorwks!CallDescrWorker+0x33
00137000 79e96571 mscorwks!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xa3
00137144 79e965a4 mscorwks!MethodDesc::CallDescr+0x19c
00137160 79e965c2 mscorwks!MethodDesc::CallTargetWorker+0x1f
00137178 7a136258 mscorwks!MethodDescCallSite::Call+0x1a
001373b0 79eab8e5 mscorwks!SecurityStackWalk::ReflectionTargetDemand+0x1ea
0013743c 79e905b5 mscorwks!AccessCheckOptions::DemandMemberAccess+0xb0
00137454 79e90544 mscorwks!ClassLoader::CheckAccess+0x8b
00137484 79eab960 mscorwks!ClassLoader::CanAccess+0x26
001374c4 79eab146 mscorwks!InvokeUtil::CheckAccess+0xa9
00137500 79eab2de mscorwks!InvokeUtil::CheckAccess+0x3a
00137558 79eac262 mscorwks!CanAccess+0xb3
001375c4 79eac328 mscorwks!PerformSecurityCheckHelper+0xb5
00137678 792d5281 mscorwks!ReflectionInvocation::PerformSecurityCheck+0xb8
001376a8 792d50be mscorlib_ni+0x215281
00137780 79f9816e mscorlib_ni+0x2150be
0013787c 79f9827b mscorwks!COMToCLRWorkerBody+0x1de
001378d8 79f986e1 mscorwks!COMToCLRWorkerDebuggerWrapper+0x37
00137abc 055ba5a1 mscorwks!COMToCLRWorker+0x52f
00137ae4 77553359 0x55ba5a1
00137b34 7deae63e ole32!OleSaveToStream+0x63
00137ba8 7deb0a75 mshtml!CObjectElement::SaveToDataStream+0x6a
00137dd0 7dd87e73 mshtml!CObjectElement::Save+0x6f
00137dec 7dd888f3 mshtml!CTreeSaver::SaveElement+0xd4
00137e8c 7dd9d1bc mshtml!CTreeSaver::Save+0x3a7
00138464 7dd9d7c7 mshtml!CMarkup::SaveToStream+0x104
00138488 7dd9df2f mshtml!CMarkup::SaveToStream+0x13f
00138ad8 7deacff1 mshtml!CMarkup::Save+0x278
0013cb0c 7deb29e3 mshtml!CFrameSite::Save+0x197
0013cb24 7dd87e73 mshtml!CIFrameElement::Save+0x15
0013cb40 7dd888f3 mshtml!CTreeSaver::SaveElement+0xd4
0013cbe0 7dd9d1bc mshtml!CTreeSaver::Save+0x3a7
0013d1b8 7dd9d7c7 mshtml!CMarkup::SaveToStream+0x104
0013d1dc 7dd9df2f mshtml!CMarkup::SaveToStream+0x13f
0013d82c 7dd759db mshtml!CMarkup::Save+0x278
0013d84c 7dd75f32 mshtml!CDoc::SaveToTempFile+0xe4
0013dd30 7dd361cd mshtml!CDoc::PrintHandler+0x2dc
0013e0e0 7dda1f06 mshtml!CDoc::ExecHelper+0x3f2
0013e10c 7dd81a78 mshtml!CWindow::print+0xa8
0013e124 7dcf0e19 mshtml!COmWindowProxy::print+0x3e
0013e130 7dcbeb03 mshtml!Method_void_void+0x17
0013e1b0 7dcbe99f mshtml!CBase::ContextInvokeEx+0x462
0013e1dc 7dcbe966 mshtml!CBase::InvokeEx+0x25
0013e244 7dcbddb2 mshtml!COmWindowProxy::InvokeEx+0x248
0013e26c 75c729d7 mshtml!COmWindowProxy::subInvokeEx+0x26
0013e2a4 75c72947 jscript!IDispatchExInvokeEx2+0xac
0013e2dc 75c731e5 jscript!IDispatchExInvokeEx+0x56
0013e34c 75c71c0a jscript!InvokeDispatchEx+0x78
0013e394 75c71211 jscript!VAR::InvokeByName+0xba
0013e3d4 75c711c6 jscript!VAR::InvokeDispName+0x43
0013e3f8 75c7311d jscript!VAR::InvokeByDispID+0xfd
0013e4b0 75c71123 jscript!CScriptRuntime::Run+0x176c
0013e4c8 75c72f89 jscript!ScrFncObj::Call+0x8d
0013e554 75c71b32 jscript!NameTbl::InvokeInternal+0xe0
0013e580 75c7311d jscript!VAR::InvokeByDispID+0xd4
0013e638 75c71123 jscript!CScriptRuntime::Run+0x176c
0013e650 75c70f8a jscript!ScrFncObj::Call+0x8d
0013e6c0 75c72642 jscript!CSession::Execute+0xa7
0013e7b0 75c724fe jscript!NameTbl::InvokeDef+0x179
0013e830 75c72e10 jscript!NameTbl::InvokeEx+0xcb
0013e860 7dcc41dd jscript!NameTbl::Invoke+0x55
0013e8f4 7dcc40e5 mshtml!CWindow::ExecuteTimeoutScript+0x85
0013e914 7dcc2562 mshtml!CWindow::FireTimeOut+0x40
0013e924 7dcc2529 mshtml!GWMouseProc+0x127
0013ea5c 7e418734 mshtml!GlobalWndProc+0x1e2
0013ea88 7e418816 USER32!InternalCallWinProc+0x28
0013eaf0 7e4189cd USER32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x150
0013eb50 7e418a10 USER32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x306
0013eb60 75f9d875 USER32!DispatchMessageW+0xf
0013eb78 75fa5218 BROWSEUI!TimedDispatchMessage+0x33
0013edd8 75fa5389 BROWSEUI!BrowserThreadProc+0x336
0013ee6c 75fa5655 BROWSEUI!BrowserProtectedThreadProc+0x50
0013fef0 7e319834 BROWSEUI!SHOpenFolderWindow+0x22c
0013ff10 00402372 SHDOCVW!IEWinMain+0x133
0013ff60 00402444 iexplore!WinMainT+0x2de
0013ffc0 7c817077 iexplore!_ModuleEntry+0x99
0013fff0 00000000 kernel32!BaseProcessStart+0x23
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this on another machine with a similar setup?

Comment: How mission critical is it that you must support IE6?

Comment: Yes i am able to reproduce this on every machine which runs IE6. It is very important to fix this as all most all of users use IE6 although i have been trying to get them upgraded to latest version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE 6.0 crashing when printing from my web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617397/ie-6-0-crashing-when-printing-from-my-web-application)