# installing debugging tools to analyse minidumps on windows 7

Tags: windows, crash, crash-dumps, minidump

I've been trying to install the 'Debugging Tools', in order to try to analyse the dump file a server-crash (Windows Server 2008 R2).

I used to do this in the past, but I cannot find how to install / locate the Debugging Tools for Windows 7.

I've read this KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263.

I've then tried to download the 'Debugging Tools for Windows' from the following article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx).  I chose the 'Install Debugging Tools for Windows as a Standalone component', downloaded the file and installed.

It did install successfully, yet I still cannot locate the files.  This seems like a silly question to me, but I cannot locate the debugging tools in any way!  I've even tried to download the mentioned Debugging tools for Windows 7 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279), yet again could not locate them!

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. I searched my whole system and no trace of windbg was found. I didn't bother to find the reason. Instead, I paused the installer and found the windbg MSI file in the temp directory and directly installed it. It works well.

In case someone want the file, I put it here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5395920/windbg-x86-6.12.0002.633.msi . The version is 6.12.0002.633 (x86) and its MD5/SHA1 is 2bd67a7b00507ad93539e138a4a6a2bf / 117814c255f19dc67e769c668bc97e547c05a55b. It's also here, directly from Microsoft http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/A/A6AC035D-DA3F-4F0C-ADA4-37C8E5D34E3D/setup/WinSDKDebuggingTools/dbg_x86.msi, but I don't know how long it will last.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to find windbg.exe

```
cd /d c:
dir /s windbg.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Kinda similar problem here:

The Win SDK installer for Win7 which contains Debugging Tools always fails. 
However in the install log one can find the above mentioned link http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/A/A6AC035D-DA3F-4F0C-ADA4-37C8E5D34E3D/setup/WinSDKDebuggingTools/dbg_x86.msi

This installer runs fine !

If someone needs other tools from the Win SDK: there are more msi installer links in the log !

Answer (score 0):

I went through the Win SDK installer fail again yesterday on yet another system. I removed all references to the MVC++ 10 complier (again), but the installer still fails (even with the compiler checkbox unselected).

I need cdb.exe for a new Qt setup. There's an MSDN archive that can be found here - http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/debugtoolswindows/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4912

Although I used a different dbg_x86.msi, this one seems to be similar in byte count, etc. and it's from Microsoft's site.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you might wanna try the "Standalone Debugging Tools for Windows 8.1" found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365). See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22077391/499721) for more details.