# How to get Windbg x86 version?

Tags: windows, x86, windbg

I have a x64 machine and want to install Windbg (x86). I went on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx to download the Debugging Tools. However, only Windbg (x64) was installed.

The reason why I want the x86 version is because I am having issues debugging x86 applications which I do not encounter when using Windbg (x86).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736250/getting-windbg-without-the-whole-wdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WinDbg](https://aka.ms/windbg), formerly WinDbg Preview, will detect 32/64 bit and attach accordingly.

*original answer*:

I had trouble finding it a couple weeks ago as well. Ultimately I went to windbg.org, which linked me to the download I wanted. Check it out and see if that's what you need.

Comment: The site looks shady though.

Comment: @drum It's not shady. It's run by a guy who has been around for years.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is get the latest SDK or DDK (now called the WDK) for Windows. The newest version of the Debugging Tools are included in the latest of each of these.

Installation directory

These are the default installation directories for Debugging Tools for Windows:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.x\Debuggers\x64
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.x\Debuggers\x86

Excerpt from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx

Start here for an overview of Debugging Tools for Windows. This tool set includes WinDbg and other debuggers. The driver development environment and the Windows debuggers are integrated into Microsoft Visual Studio.

•To set up the integrated environment, install Visual Studio and then install the Windows Driver Kit (WDK). Debugging Tools for Windows is included in the WDK. You can get the integrated environment here.

•If you don't need the WDK, you can get Debugging Tools for Windows as part of the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8.1. You can get the Windows SDK for Windows 8.1 here.

•If you want to download only Debugging Tools for Windows, install the Windows SDK, and, during the installation, select the Debugging Tools for Windows box and clear all the other boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Here gives the direct download links from Microsoft official.

### WinDbg, formerly WinDbg Preview

will detect 32/64 bit and attach accordingly.

Download: https://aka.ms/windbg

The older versions are now called WinDbg classic.

### Windbg for windows 7 - download

x86: http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/A/A6AC035D-DA3F-4F0C-ADA4-37C8E5D34E3D/setup/WinSDKDebuggingTools/dbg_x86.msi

x64: http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/A/A6AC035D-DA3F-4F0C-ADA4-37C8E5D34E3D/setup/WinSDKDebuggingTools_amd64/dbg_amd64.msi

### Windbg for windows 10 (WinDbg 10.0.18362.1) - download

x86: https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/2/2/42245968-6A79-4DA7-A5FB-08C0AD0AE661/windowssdk/Installers/X86%20Debuggers%20And%20Tools-x86_en-us.msi

x64: https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/2/2/42245968-6A79-4DA7-A5FB-08C0AD0AE661/windowssdk/Installers/X64%20Debuggers%20And%20Tools-x64_en-us.msi

### Windbg preview (WindbgX) from Microsoft Store

https://www.microsoft.com/store/p/windbg/9pgjgd53tn86

---

Source:
https://github.com/yanglr/advDotnetDebugging/blob/main/README.md

WinDbg Preview from Microsoft Store will no longer receive updates since it has been replaced by official WinDbg (see above).